# Can I load a C++ shared library built with address sanitizer from Rust?

Tags: c++, rust, address-sanitizer, treesitter

In tree-sitter, grammars are compiled from C and C++ to shared libraries. These libraries are then dynamically loaded by the tree-sitter CLI, which is a rust program. The tree-sitter CLI is usually responsible for compiling the grammar, although it does so without `-fsanitize` flags. I manually compiled my grammar with `-fsanitize=address` (eventually want to add `undefined`) to help with debugging some C++ code I wrote as part of the external scanner. However, when I try to load it with the tree-sitter CLI rust program I get:

> Error opening dynamic library "~/.cache/tree-sitter/lib/tlaplus.so"
>
> Caused by:
> ~/.cache/tree-sitter/lib/tlaplus.so: undefined symbol: __asan_report_store4

So rust isn't loading ASAN. I tred rebuilding the tree-sitter CLI with the nightly rust toolchain and:

```bash
RUSTFLAGS="-Z sanitizer=address" cargo build --target x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu --release
```

But this still gives the same undefined symbol error. Is there any way to load a C++ library compiled with ASAN from rust, or should I just write my own C++ front end to the grammar?

Answer (score 2):

According to https://maxammann.org/posts/2021/06/sanitize-rust-sys-crate/

```
RUSTFLAGS="-C link-arg=-lasan"
```